# TensorFlow image processing error: "TypeError: 'MapDataset' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to follow this guide here on semantic segmentation : https://yann-leguilly.gitlab.io/post/2019-12-14-tensorflow-tfdata-segmentation/ and I'm stuck at building a pipeline.

I am running into an error when I'm applying a script to resize and rotate images from the training set. The transformation is defined in the function `load_image_train()`. The error reads :

```
raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert 
this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Tracing the error in `load_image_train()`, I am stuck at running this line:
`input_image = tf.image.resize(datapoint['image'], (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))`

Here `datapoint` is a `dict` item of four `tf.Dataset`s:

```
>>> dataset
{'train': <MapDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), segmentation_mask: (None, None, 1)}, types: {image: tf.uint8, segmentation_mask: tf.uint8}>, 'val': <MapDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), segmentation_mask: (None, None, 1)}, types: {image: tf.uint8, segmentation_mask: tf.uint8}>}
```

I can subset `dataset['train']` but I can't subset further. subsetting `dataset['train']['image']` is not allowed for `MapDataset` objects:

```
>>> dataset['train']['image']  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'MapDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

I suspect this is where the error comes from. So how can I go about choosing only the `image` from the training set and apply the transformations? Thanks!

Comment: `dataset['train'].map(load_image_train, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` Are you not already doing this ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Yes that's the line that gave me the error `raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a 'tf.Tensor' as a Python 'bool' is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert 
this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.`

Comment: But when I execute that in Google colab I don't see that error. Do you want to customize that code ? Is that the question ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Yes, I need to tweak it for my data. I have tracked down the error to the random rotation section `if tf.random.uniform(())> 0.5 :`. It appears that TensorFlow does not allow this type of comparison when it's part of a `tf.function`? In that case how am I supposed to make the random draw to the uniform and rotate the images randomly?

Comment: You are referring to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#setup). Colab is using 2.6.0 and it is decorated with `tf.function`. It works in Colab. Is your local version different ?

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan I have 2.5 installed locally

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan I tried re-writing that comparison to a more "TensorFlowish" way: `tf.math.greater(tf.random.uniform(shape=[]), 0.5)` it's still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it to work on my local machine. I had to resort to `tf.cond` for that comparison statement. I'm still not sure why the comparison with Python operators didn't work even though my TensorFlow is of version 2.5.

Replace the statement:

```
if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
        input_image = tf.image.flip_left_right(input_image)
        input_mask = tf.image.flip_left_right(input_mask)
```

with:

```
    draw = tf.random.uniform(shape=[])

    input_image = tf.cond(tf.math.greater(draw, 0.5),
        lambda: tf.image.flip_left_right(input_image),
        lambda: input_image)

    input_mask = tf.cond(tf.math.greater(draw, 0.5),
        lambda: tf.image.flip_left_right(input_mask),
        lambda: input_mask)
```